# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on remove row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the following code that I want to use to recalculate totals when a user removes a row from a datagridview.

```
private void RemoveRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (GridSellProducts.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 7)
      {
           if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove the row?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
           {
                 GridSellProducts.Rows.Remove(GridSellProducts.CurrentRow);

                 vatTotalCalculate();
                 amtTotalCalculate();
           }
      }
}

private void vatTotalCalculate()
{
      decimal vatSum = 0;
      decimal vSum = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < GridSellProducts.Rows.Count; ++i)
      {
            if (GridSellProducts.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() != null) <--exception thrown here
            {
                 if (Decimal.TryParse((GridSellProducts.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()), out vatSum))
                        vSum += vatSum;
            }
      }

      txtVATTotal.Text = vSum.ToString();
}
```

The exception is thrown at the line if `(GridSellProducts.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() != null)`
}
Calling the calculate methods from

```
 private void ValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
      {
           vatTotalCalculate();
      }
 }
```

throws no exceptions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try using Convert.ToString, instead of using .ToString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GridSellProducts.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()
```

if `Value` is null then you cannot do `ToString()`

```
if (GridSellProducts.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value != null) 
{
    ....
```